# What can I use polenta leftovers for?

Tags: culinary-uses, polenta

When we make polenta, we use polenta leftovers for lunch, grilling them.
Are there any other uses for polenta leftovers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My wife makes (made up?) a super-quick tasty dish:

Sautee spinach, mushrooms & garlic (2 cloves if you like it garlicky)

layer polenta on the bottom of a baking dish 
Add spinach/mushroom/garlic mix 
Add black beans (1 can)
Mix in a little salsa
Cover with cheese

Bake at 350 for 20-25 minutes until the cheese is melted.

Answer (score 2):

You can slice it thin, cut it into pieces, dip into flour and fry it in oil or butter according to your preference.  Or use it as a base for something with a sauce like chicken cacciatore.  Enjoy!

Comment: Frying it in flat chunks is best, be patient and fry in it olive oil until the edges turn dark, then flip it over.  Once it's all crunchy then use either a savory (balsamic or wine based) or sweet (maple syrup or fruity yogurt) depending on what kind of polenta it was.  Putting more cornmeal on it is a good idea, but not important, it will brown on its own.

Answer (score 2):

slice it, top it with a little tomato sauce or tomato slices, basil and mozzarella, toss into the oven for a few minutes until its warmed and the cheese is melty (or nuke it). Maybe add a slice of pepperoni.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep it in the fridge for few days. The simplest way to reuse it is to grill it and then serve with cheese (like gorgonzola) or crème fraiche.

Answer (score 1):

You can serve them with a good dripping of **aged** balsamic vinegar. Also, if you have access to Italian soft cheeses, like [Squacquerone](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squacquerone) or [Stracchino](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stracchino), they get along really well.